# Cloud Dataflow - Heap Space error while using PcollectionList

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have to partition the data by a date field in it. I am doing it using Partition Transform.

When I divide yearly data by month, Partition returns a Pcollectionlist which has 12 pcollection. This works fine.

When I have to divide it by day. I will have to create 1*12*31 Pcollection in PcollectionList. This throughs Heap space error. I tried only for 2 months data. That is,

```
a PcollectionList of 2*31 Pcollection
```

I tried using n1-highmem-4 and n1-highmem-8 machines with more than 10 workers. Still it throughs Heap space error. I am testing with only 2.0 MiB file. So I believe data size should not be a problem. The screen shots are below.

[image]

[image]

Please help me to fix this. Or a work around to my solution is also most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to get time-based divisions of your data. Have you looked at [windowing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing)? It should allow you to do monthly/daily/hourly windowing without needing to perform the partition. If windowing isn't applicable, could you explain why you need to partition by day?

How are you consuming the partitioned results? You may be running into a [known bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/62) with pipelines with many sinks running into OOM errors due to the byte buffers for each of the sinks.

Comment: If I am not wrong, windowing groups the elements by the time it arrives in Dataflow. My use case is different. I am dealing with transaction data. Lets say I have a field called "transaction_date", I need to group the transactions by the transaction_date field and persist the data in different BQ table. I tried GroupBy, it returns a Pcollection<KV<date, Iterable<TableRow>>>, but I believe I could sink only Pcollection<TableRow> in BQ. And when I tried creating a Pcollection<TableRow> from Iterable<TableRow> using a tranform, I couldn't do that since I need a pipeline for Create.of(Values).

Comment: Windowing groups the elements by a per-element timestamp referred to as "event time". With PubSub, the default assignment of timestamps is as you say -- the arrival time. But, you can use PubSubIO to set specific timestamps (such as the time it was published or some other property of the data). See [PubSubIO.Read#timestampLabel](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/PubsubIO.Read#timestampLabel-java.lang.String-) for more info.

Comment: I am doing a batch processing using TEXTIO. I will get a file which has Yearly transaction data. I need to do some imputation on that. Group the data by month using transaction date fieldand sink it in separate table created by month name suffix. I hope now my use case is clear.

Comment: In the case of Batch, what you can do is start with all the input elements at the timestamp of the beginning of the year. Then you can use the [WithTimestamps](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/WithTimestamps) transform to re-timestamp specific events based on the timestamp in the event. Any windowing after that will use the timestamp of the event to assign windows.